# abntex2/ufctex translating the word 'and' in citations

Tags: bibtex, citing, abnt

I'm writing my dissertation in english, but university's library forces us to use their latex package, originally in Brazilian portuguese, for all works like this. The problem is that when we choose english at the languages options citations still stay in portuguese, instead of *Author1 **and** Author2* [YEAR], it shows *Author1 **e** Author2* [YEAR].

I'd like to know if there is some way of forcing the translation of **e** to **and**, without editing the package.

[Template](https://pt.sharelatex.com/project/57740f53c4b5936215e82746)

Comment: Are you using BibTeX or Biblatex ? If you don't know, I will assume that you are using BibTeX .
 The "problem" then comes from the ``.bst`style that you are using. Which is it ?

Comment: By looking at yours "template link" I see that you use BibTeX , but din't find the ``\bibliographystyle`` command...
Perhaps can you find its name when runing the ``makefile``...

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. You can edit the `.bst` file, or use the `biblatex-abnt` package:

```
\usepackage[style=abnt]{biblatex}
```